# window.postMessage to popups in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, dom-events, postmessage

What I want to do:
opening an popup and send the postMessage when the popup is ready.

Problem:
I ran into Race Condition which the popup is not ready but the message is sent.  I tried to listen to the "INIT" message and in the popup send back message.  But the problem is when network latency or some slow computer will not receive the initial message.

The setTimeout obviously not a good solution

Code I have problem with:
Parent Window

```
    const windowFeatures  = "height=800,width=1280,toolbar=1,menubar=1,location=1"; 
    const printWindow = window.open("/print", "Print_Me", windowFeatures);

    setTimeout(() => {printWindow.postMessage({printPageStatus: "INIT"}, window.origin)}, 1000)

    window.addEventListener("message", (event) => { 
      if(event.origin !== window.origin)  return;  
      if(event.data.printPageStatus === "READY") {
        printWindow.postMessage({message: "from parent", window.origin);
        return;
      }
    });
```

The popup window

```
 constructor() {
    window.addEventListener("message", event => {
      if(event.origin !== window.origin)  return;    
      if(event.data.printPageStatus === "INIT")
        this.sendReadyConfirmation(event);
      if(event.data.message === "from parent") {
        this.processMessages(event.data);
      }
    }, false);
 }

  sendReadyConfirmation(e): void {
    e.source.postMessage({printPageStatus: "READY"}, e.origin);
  }
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you try to `sendReadyConfirmation` in `ngOnInit` instead ?

Comment: I tried that, didn't work for me..  The problem is Initial message which sent by the parent has race condition issue.  setTimeout longer like 5 sec will work most case but that is not a good solution.

Comment: I don't get why you `sendReadyConfirmation` in the `addEventListener`. I roughly understand what you want to do (wait for the window to be ready before sending data) but it seems to me that to just need to `sendReadyConfirmation`, either in the `constructor` on `ngOnInit` directly. What is the point of listening for message before sending the "READY" message ?

Comment: This is just trying to confirm the communication is happening...
Ritesh Waghela mentioned using onload and kinda work...  I am still having some issues

Comment: window.parent in popup doesnt work..  I guess only work for iFrame.
So, in the parent I sent "INIT" message to child popup and have Child confirm the message is received and "READY" before sending another message..
Yes, it looks no point to doing that.  But simply If there is way communication to the parent window in the popup, that would be great.
As Ritesh Waghela mentioned below, the onload event will know when the child popups is launched and then send the message..  it works better but sometime the child pop up still not getting the message.  1 second setTimeout with onload will work

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is send the message when the window has loaded successfully :

```
const printWindow = window.open("/print", "Print_Me", windowFeatures);
 printWindow.onload = () => {
   printWindow.postMessage({printPageStatus: "INIT"}, window.origin)
};
```

Comment: @Zeo, did it work?

Comment: It is working better....  But not all the time...  I am seeing why the message is not happening sometime, will let you know

Comment: it works better but sometime the child pop up still not getting the message. 1 second setTimeout within onload will work 100%